# Sci-fi kids' book about a pilot's flight through space, and the ships he encounters along the way

Tags: story-identification, books, space, illustrated-story

The book is probably from the 70's or 80's, and is small, short, and written for a juvenile reader. It's illustrated in color.
The book presents you as the pilot of a small spacecraft, and as you travel, you encounter various spaceships. Each encounter includes a illustrated scene and short exposition on the ship.
There may have been an included a 7 inch LP record.

Some details that I *think* I can recall:

- I think, the book is narrated by your ship's computer.
- There's an opening illustration of your cockpit from the first person.
- You encounter a mining ship called the Rostov.
- A tall multi-ringed space station called Orion.
- Some space fighters with a flat downward swept nose. Maybe of some space patrol force.
- I think, an unidentified alien ship.